# MySQL : find repeating events that are outdated

Tags: mysql, sql

I've looked for solutions but couldn't find anything for my specific problem and can't manage to sort it on my own, the queries I'm trying are too heavy and timeout my server.

I have a table 'events' like this :

```
+-----------+--------------------------------+
| field     | informations                   |
+-----------+--------------------------------+
| id        | INT(11) PRIMARY AUTO_INCREMENT |
| repeat_id | INT(11)                        |
| timestamp | TIMESTAMP                      |
| title     | VARCHAR(255)                   |
| details   | TEXT                           |
+-----------+--------------------------------+
```

My events cane be unique (*'repeat_id'=0*) or repeated (*'repeat_id'>0*), and my problem is, I want to find all "outdated" events, that is to say the events that are repeated AND whose max timestamp is under current timestamp.

It might be easy using the good synthax and/or functions but I can't manage to do it... any help would be appreciated!

Thanks a lot,

Arthur

Comment: Show us the queries that you have tried and that failed first.

Comment: Please show some sample data, since it is also not clear if the title or the repeat_id is an id for repeating events (or are they repeatedly in the table?)

Also mention desired outcome for that data.

And check if your connection opening/closing is correct... Maybe you have an error there..

Comment: Hi @neuhaus ! I tried several queries adapted from what I could found on topics of peaople who had simalar problems, but didn't keep it as they didn't work or took too long to exacute. _Rahul_ found the perfect answer using **HAVING** as shown below. Anyway, thanks for helping! :)

Comment: Hi @Pieter21! The different entries of the same event repeated will have a commom 'repeat_id' value, so I group on this field. My opening and closing are OK and as a result I just want all the rows that fit what I want. _Rahul_ found the perfect answer using **HAVING** as shown below. Anyway, thanks for helping! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you try like below

```
select * from events
where repeat_id > 0
group by title
having max(`timestamp`) <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: Yeaaah thank you @Rahul !
I didn't know about **HAVING** and that's what I was looking for.
Your query is exactly what I need except that I group by _repeat_id_ and not _title_.